# Simple ItemsSource for testing purposes

Tags: wpf, binding

Can someone show me a system-enumerable that I can access quickly as an ItemsSource to get test-data. I do not care what type it returns. The amount of data is also not very relevant, 100 or 10000 items, I do not care.

The desired markup would then look something like the code below and idealy does not need any namespace-declaration:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{x:Static ASystemEnumerableThatReturnsSomeObjects}"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a bit partial to using the system fonts for static xaml arrays:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{x:Static Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I like using String for testing, since it works as an enumerable of char.  In .NET 4.0 you can use a string directly:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="asdf"/>
```

For earlier versions, you could use a static property of type String:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{x:Static DataFormats.Text}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `System.Net.HttpStatusCode` enumeration and look at the following [link](http://www.ageektrapped.com/blog/the-missing-net-7-displaying-enums-in-wpf/) to know how to use it as an items source. The given link demonstrates using an enum as the ItemSource for a `ComboBox` but you can use it with a `ListBox` as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm looking for something really short (for testing purposes).